# Sympy - altering the range of the y axis for a plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, sympy

Using Sympy how does one set the range for the y axis ?

```
plot((x**2 + 2))
```

I wanted to have this so that the y axis would be from 0 to 7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you plot you can use the kwargs `xlim` and `ylim` to set the axis limits.

For example:

```
>>> plot((x**2 + 2), xlim=[-3,3], ylim=[0,7])
```

[image]

Comment: ah thats ace thanks, I tried to use them from the docs but didn't set them correctly, this works thanks

Comment: Is there a reason to use a mutable list for arguments when an immutable tuple is lighter for the CPU?