# how to make axes be the right length in plot of sympy

Tags: python, plot, sympy

```py
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy import *
plot(*Array([4,6,8]).applyfunc(lambda m:sec(x).series(n=m).removeO()),sec(x),(x,-pi/2,pi/2),ylim=(0,4))
```

this gives out

[image]

I want the y-axes to be from 0-4

I have read the Keyword Arguments, but didn't find any other handle expect ylim.

Comment: Note that just plotting `plot(x*x+1, ylim=(0, 4))` also has this empty space between 0 and 1. (And not setting the `ylim` gives an even weirder plot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the standard way sympy draws plots that don't cross the x-axis. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881624/sympy-altering-the-range-of-the-y-axis-for-a-plot) is another post with a similar plot.

A possible workarround is to draw an invisible plot near 0,0:

```py
from sympy import plot, pi, sec
from sympy.abc import x

plot1 = plot(*Array([4, 6, 8]).applyfunc(lambda m: sec(x).series(n=m).removeO()), sec(x), 
             (x, -pi / 2, pi / 2), ylim=(0, 4), show=False)
plot2 = plot(0, (x, 0, 1 / 1000), line_color='none', show=False)
plot1.append(plot2[0])
plot1.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

Note that for more complex customization, the plot can be [moved to matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813804/12046409).

Comment: Yes, it is. Sympy's plotting tends to be quick and without much options. There are some even more [tricky ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46813804/12046409) to move the plots to matplotlib and do the customization there.